# "Печь торт" и "одевать шапку" — правильно ли так сказать?

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов

Слышал, что так неверно говорить, но подробной информации не нашел, особенно касательно торта.

Comment: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/trudnosti?layout=item&id=36_119

Answer (score 4):

Ну, про сладкую парочку "*одеть/надеть*" даже мемы есть, в них обычно очень сердятся защитники грамматики, назовем их так. Одеть можно кого-то (во что-то), например: *одеть девочку в платье, одеть куклу*. Надеть можно что-то (на кого-то), например: *надеть шапку, надеть варежки* и т. п.

Что касается тортов, то в первый раз слышу о каких-либо ограничениях, но удалось найти [похожий вопрос с вполне разумным ответом на gramota.ru](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82): "*профессиональные кондитеры возмущаются, когда слышат словосочетание **печь торт**, они говорят **собирать торт***".

Суть в следующем: словосочетание корректно, но в профессиональной среде кто-то придумал, что так говорить нельзя. Пекут коржи, а торты не пекут. Так же в авиации из суеверия не говорят "*последний рейс*" (в значении "предыдущий"), а говорят "*крайний*".

Если вы не кондитер, то можете смело ***печь торты***.

Answer (score 2):

Где-то 10 лет назад (да и лет 150 назад, во времена классиков) у слова ‟одевать” было минимум два значения: одевать кого-то (инвалида, ребенка), одевать предмет гардероба (на себя или других). Но однажды какой-то грамотей-самодур проснулся с желанием убрать одно из значений этого слова — и преуспел в навязывании этой бессмысленный нормы. Теперь, если вы используете слово ‟одевать” в значении одевать предмет гардероба, то вас будут поправлять.
Что касается слова ‟печь”, то, возможно, этот же самодур добрался и до этого слова.

Если кто не верит, что классики использовали слово ‟одевать” минимум в двух значениях, то вот несколько примеров:
А состряпав обед, убирала комнату, мылась, одевала чистое платье и садилась за стол к окну чинить что-нибудь из одёжи. Горький Максим, Трое, 1901
Никоим образом не мог ожидать… но вот сюда, сюда! Вот здесь, на диван, или сюда, в кресла, а я… — И он бросился одевать сюртук, забыв надеть жилет. Достоевский Ф. М., Вечный муж, 1870

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130951/discussion-on-answer-by-jim-korbett--------).